# SwiftUI: How to setup WindowGroup for multiple project/editor windows (macOS 13)

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm working on an app that allows the user to create projects. The user should be able to open several projects simultaneuosly (each in its own window) but also to open multiple windows containing the same project. It's similar to how Xcode works, being able to have multiple editor windows for each project.

I'm struggling with setting up the `WindowGroup` correctly for this. At the moment I am using this code, which allows me to open each project in a new window:

```
WindowGroup(id: "project-window", for: Project.ID.self) { $projectId in
    ContentView(projectId: projectId)
}
```

The problem is now that when I call `openWindow(id: "project-window", value: project.id)` and there is already a window for this project, this window will come to the front but no new window will be opened.

How do I set this up correctly that there can be multiple windows for the same project? I suppose I might have create a `WindowGroup` for each project, use the projectId as the ID for the `WindowGroup` and an UUID as value, but can't figure out how to do this properly.

Target for this project is macOS 13.

EDIT: The app is not document based.

Answer (score 0):

This is designed to be used this way and 99,9% apps need it to be like that.

The Xcode doesn't work like that. It has files for each document in the project and each file has its id which would be sent in this case. Possibly you need to review your data structure.

Alternatively you can use older `WindowGroup` APIs (without ids) and URLs to launch them, that will always generate a new window.